# Change SonarQube's Quality Profile Based on File Name

Tags: java, sonarqube

It's really easy to have use cases where a SonarQube rule can be important for some files, but completely useless for others, I'll just give some examples:

The rule **"Missing translations should be added"** is really great for finding missing keys in all kinds of *messages_xx.properties*. However each group of properties files always has an empty *messages_en.properties* (at least for us, where English is the default locale). For this files it's an actual bug to add keys to.

Another example is **"String literals should not be duplicated"**: in normal Java files duplicated strings introduce bugs (because you might change one and not the other). In test files enforcing this code leads to unreadable code, because the duplicate code usually is in the initialization of the tested objects and / or the messages printed out when the test fails.

I could easily go on with how test cases differ from "real" Java classes. Even though test code should have the same quality measurements, in practice it's quite different.

The question is now: How to handle these rules in Sonar?

The trivial answers I already discarded:

- remove the rules entirely (they are quite useful)
- fix the rules (the first example even introduces bugs into the code)
- mark the test as `won't fix` (it's just too much)

So I guess I want to change the Quality Profile based on the project (e.g. exclude `org.acme.project.it`) or a file name (e.g. exclude **Test.java*). Or maybe enable rules only for some file name patterns.

What is the best way to handle SonarQube rules that only work on a specific group of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [set up some exclusions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus). Exclusions allow you to ignore certain files completely, or to conversely ignore all but the specified set of files. You can set up exclusions for coverage or duplications. And most pertinently to your question, you can set up multiple flavors of issue exclusions.